# sudo command not working

Tags: sudo

When I try to use the command `sudo mountall`, the following error message appears:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/username/1: No such file or directory
```

So how do I solve this?

Comment: Any command at all?

Comment: @muru , i'm sorry , i forget to set the complete command , the question edited

Comment: Can you add output from /etc/fstab?

    `cat /etc/fstab`

Is there some any problem on system such as unable create file, other command with sudo, etc.?

How long you have this problem?

Comment: @Letizia, "no such file or directory" != "read only filesystem".

Comment: @psusi, you are right, I removed my wrong comment.